# Текстовый редактор

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте, пишу текстовый редактор на паскале :) Думаю как организовать ввод, была мысль  сделать массив со строками, просто мы в текстовом редакторе, иногда начинаем писать с новой строки, а при помощи стандартной процедуры read после того, как нажмём enter, он записывает в переменную, то, что вводит юзер, я думаю сделать типа цикла, и если юзер нажал ентер, то просто добавлять старую строку в массив, и создаём новую, но вот не уверен в правильности такого решения, и как в паскале настроить сочетании HotKeys, нужно как поймать событие когда юзер нажимает ctrl+s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью read[ln] вы реализуете не текстовый редактор, а строковый. Да, тут циклом читаете построчно, заносите в массив каждую введенную строку. Получится этакий copy con.

Более интересный текстовый редактор надо писать с помощью readkey, gotoxy и т.д (гугль в помощь по модулю crt). Т.е. получаете введенный символ, и в зависимости от того что ввели выполняете действия - печатаете символ, двигаете курсор, удаляете символ и т.д. Тут и шорткаты сможете обработывать.